# Getting errors when run code for extent report

Tags: c#, extentreports

I am trying to create an extent report using C#.

But when i try to run a code (copied from web), I get these errors:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and copy paste your code. What are you doing? What programming language is this - add the relevant tag! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Specifically: please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to Extent Report version, their methods also deprecated. What you have tried to copy source from Web, make sure that Blog-report version and what are you using should same.

Instead of referring Source from web, you may refer example given by Extent community itself:

http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/net/#basic-example

In your above code, If you are using version 3+ then there is no parameter for ExtentReport class.